# Facing LTI 1.3 requires a valid openssl.cnf to be configured and available to your web server

Tags: moodle

I am integrating MS Teams with Moodle 4.3.2+. During this I am facing LTI 1.3 requires a valid openssl.cnf to be configured and available to your web server in localhost. Although the openssl has already been installed. I am attaching 2 screenshots for your reference. I have tried every solution. Any help would be appreciated.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Okqb.png)

I need to Integrate MS Team with Moodle. During the integration I have faced the above error and I have tried every solution but still error is exist. Please help.

Comment: Seems to be a common problem - try searching the Moodle site and see the answers from the forums - "site:moodle.org lti 1.3 openssl.cnf"

Comment: I have checked every possible solution but unable to solve the problem. On moodle the solution was not satisfactory and have applied those as well.